Which is better @angular/material-moment-adapter vs date-fns in Angular? Why?
In my Angular Project, I am comparing to use @angular/material-moment-adapter vs date-fns to handle date formatting.
As of my knowledge, moment.js and date-fns do the very similar thing to handle date, but date-fns is more light-weight than moment.js in JavaScript applications.
To use @angular/material-moment-adapter, we also need to install moment.js to be compitable with. And also @angular/material-moment-adapter doesn't have proper documentation to use. So, I don't know what is the benefits of using this.
To use date-fns, we can use it independently and also have proper documentation and also light-weight.
So, my question is which one should I choose to get better advantages and performance? and give me some reasons why? Thank you.

Short: Use plain JS Date with Angular instead of momentJS.
MomentJS ist more or less "dead". See: MomentJS - Project Status
The @angular/material-moment-adapter is only required if you use momentJS, because otherwise the Material DatePicker for example returns JS Dates instead of Moment Objects.
In terms of performance date-fns is also the winner. It uses the JS Date Object, momentJS uses it's own Object with a bit of overhead.
